# Two different standard deviations?

Tags: inference

I'm reading this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119163668) and on page 419 the authors state the following theorem:

[image]

I'm really confused. What is the standard deviation? $\sigma$ or $\sigma/\sqrt{n}$?

Comment: Interesting. My understanding is that the equation, $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$, is the standard error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the confusion disappears once you realise that the theorem talks about *two* distributions.

The first distribution is the *population*, which has a mean $\mu$ and a standard deviation $\sigma$.
Let's assume the height of all humans is normal distributed, with $(\mu, \sigma) = (1.5, 0.5)$ in metres.

From that population, you draw *one* sample of size $n$, and compute its mean -- that's called the sample mean. Say you measure the height of $n=100$ people, and get a mean height for that one sample of 1.57.

Repeat many times: you'll get *a distribution of sample means*, which is the second distribution -- and that has a mean of $\mu$ and a standard deviation of $\sigma / \sqrt n$.

Answer (score 6):

Standard deviation of what? It really depends on the random variable you consider.
With that being said, let $X_i\stackrel{\text{i.i.d.}}{\sim}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$. Now $\sigma$ is obviously the standard deviation of the random variables $X_1,\ldots,X_n$, whereas $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$ denotes the standard deviation of the sample mean $\overline{X}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$.